# Vanity URL But with settings

Tags: .htaccess

Just a quick question,

I am making user profiles for my website and would like to include vanity URLS, but the page has a lot of separate information which gets loaded, e.g Followers tab, uploads tab, and each of these have some kind of setting that can be applied like ASC DESC, New/old results etc. What would be the best way to have vanity urls but keep the functionality i require?

http://www.site.com/user.php?id=1&content=Followers&Order=(Different settings for each result)

But i am wondering if it would be better if i should just name the content differently if someone wanted to search for followers + a limitation, for example

http://www.site.com/user.php?id=1&content=NewestFollowers,

rather than

http://www.site.com/user.php?id=1&content=Followers&Order=Newest

Comment: What do the non-vanity urls look like?

Comment: Without a parameter that a username can be passed to, you're going to be limited to user id's (e.g. `1`)

Comment: I can just change id to username then gather results from my database, but that wasn't my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically want to construct the vanity URL so that it directly maps to query string parameters to the ugly URL. So if you have:

```
http://www.site.com/user.php?id=1&content=Followers&Order=Newest
```

You can make your vanity URL look like:

```
http://www.site.com/u/1/Followers/Newest/
```

But the `/1/` bit is a little ugly, and not exactly vanity, so if you can pass a username through that query string parameter, it would look better:

```
http://www.site.com/u/jonlin/Followers/Newest/
```

Then you'd just put some mod_rewrite rules in an htaccess file in your document root that internally rewrites the vanity URL back to the ugly one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /user.php?id=$1&content=$2&Order=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /user.php?id=$1&content=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/?$ /user.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I see alot of websites that rather than using / to separate there urls they use #? Is there a difference and if so which would be better?

Comment: @user1527354 `#` is a URL fragment, it's never sent to the server, it's strictly client-side and is sometimes used by javascript.